# In Next.js, how can I handle all the routes and links in one file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

In Next.js, how can I handle all the routes and links in one file so that in the future, if the paths of the folders and files are changed, I don't have to change the links in the whole project?

When I put the file name as Href in the link tag, I get a 404 error and I have to put the folder name in the URL too.
for example I want this: href="/Article"
not this: href="/Article/Article"

Comment: Are you referring to a [catch all route](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes)?